# Router QBR-1041w

Tags: ssh, router, openwrt

Нашел роутер qbr-1041w - подключил и заметил что у него открыт SSH. От веб-интерфейса пароль и логин - admin;admin. А вот от SSH я низнаю. Вопрос можно ли сделать Openwrt прошивку или узнать пароль от ssh.

I found the qbr-1041w router - I connected it and noticed that it has SSH open. From the web interface, the password and login are admin; admin. But from SSH, I do not know. The question is whether to make Openwrt firmware or to learn the password from ssh.